# How to create a custom filter group in powerbi

Tags: filter, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

How would I go about grouping the elements in power bi. For instance I want to group element number 01. as x and 02. as y and such.

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymyT8.png)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it:

```
Grouping = SWITCH(TRUE(),
LEFT('Year'[Group],2)="01" , "x",
LEFT('Year'[Group],2)="02", "y",
"z")
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8HG92.png)